# Error: My every function & variable 'was not declared in this scope (code;;blocks, c++)

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm new to c++ and I wrote my first 'real' program (A simple four-operation calculator). When I compiled it I got 12 compiler errors. I was able to solve some (Missing semicolons etc.) but 7 of them  refused to go away. The errors and my code are here:

The Errors:

```
    15 error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
    15 error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope
    21 error: 'GetNumber' was not declared in this scope
    24 error: 'GetOperator' was not declared in this scope
    29 error: 'nAnswer' was not declared in this scope
    33 error: 'AskContinue' was not declared in this scope
    35 error: 'bContinue' was not declared in this scope
```

Main.cpp

```
    //Four-operation calculator
    //© Olli Utriainen 2013

    #include <iostream>
    //Header with functions GetNumber(), GetOperator() and AskContinue()
    #include "calculator.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        //Main loop's condition
        bool bContinue = false;

        cout << "Welcome to Olli's calculator!" << endl << endl;

        //Main loop
       do
        {
            cout << "Give first number" << endl;
            int nNumber1 = GetNumber();

            cout << "Give operator (+,-,*,/)" << endl;
            char cOperator = GetOperator();

            cout << "Give second number" << endl;
            int nNumber2 = GetNumber();

            nAnswer = nNumber1 + nNumber2;

            cout << nNumber1 << " " << cOperator << " " <<
            nNumber2 << " = " << nAnswer << endl;

            bContinue = AskContinue();

        } while (bcontinue);

        return 0;
    }
```

Headers.h

```
    //Headers for the calculator
    //© Olli Utriainen 2013

    #ifndef CALCULATOR_H_INCLUDED
    #define CALCULATOR_H_INCLUDED

   //Function for inputting numbers
   int GetNumber()

   //Function for inputting a mathematical operator (+,-,*,/)
   char GetOperator()

   //Function for asking Continue Yes/No
   bool AskContinue()

   #endif // CALCULATOR_H_INCLUDED
```

Functions.cpp

```
   //Functions for the calculator
   //© Olli Utriainen 2013

   #include <iostream>

   using namespace std;

   //Function for inputting numbers
   int GetNumber()
   {
       int nNumber

       cin >> nNumber;

       return nNumber
   }

   //Function for inputting a mathematical operator (+,-,*,/)
   int GetOperator()
   {
       char cOperator
       bool bValidOperator = false;

       //Do-while loop for checking if given operator
       //is valid (+,-,*,/). If invalid, bValidOperator
       //is changed to false ->loop will break and the
       //given operator is returned
       do
       {
           cin >> cOperator;

           if (cOperator == '+' || '-' || '*' || '/')
               {
                   bValidOperator = true;
               }
           else
               {
                   bValidOperator = false;
                   cout << "Invalid operator" << endl;
               }


       } while (!bValidOperator)

       return cOperator;

   }

   //Function for asking Continue Yes/No
   bool AskContinue()
   {
       cout << "New calculation? Y/N" << endl;

       bool bContinue = false;
       if (cin >> 'Y' || 'y')
           {
               bContinue = true;
           }
       if (cin >> 'N' || 'n')
           {
               bContinue = false;
           }
       return bcontinue;
   }
```

Comment: you should add tons of `;`

Comment: AskContinue() is broken, too

Comment: As you learn C++, it's a *very* good practice to write a small portion of your program, make sure it compiles and runs correctly, and then repeat.  The overall problem here was that you continued adding incorrect code to incorrect code.

Answer (score 2):

Semi-colons for function declarations in the header? Oh actually lots of semi-colons missing. Make sure you insert them where required and try again.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of typo;
Tons of semi-colons missing;

in calculator.cpp, you should #include "calculator.h"

in bool AskContinue()
it should be:

```
{
cout << "New calculation? Y/N" << endl;
bool bContinue = false;
char choice;
cin >> choice;
if ((choice == 'Y')||(choice == 'y'))
{
   bContinue = true;
}
   if ((choice == 'N')||(choice == 'n'))
{
   bContinue = false;
}
   return bContinue;
}
```

These are what I can found by now.